# The order of convert byte array to hex string

Tags: java, string, byte

I see the internet has a lot of method that convert the byte array to string. Like this one:

```
static private String hexEncode(byte[] aInput) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    char[] digits = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f'};
    for (int idx = 0; idx < aInput.length; ++idx) {
        byte b = aInput[idx];
        result.append(digits[ (b&0xf0) >> 4 ]);  // why does this line come first
        result.append(digits[ b&0x0f ]); // why is this line put behind
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

I am wondering why the high 4 number is put previous on the hex string.

**For example**:

*aInput:*

```
{ 00110001, 00010011, 01100001 }
```

*hex string:*

```
"311361"
```

I am wondering why it can't be `133116`.

Comment: Because generally you want the most-significant bits to correspond to the most-significant hex digit.

Comment: in other words `0b00110001` = `0x31` so normally one would expect that the String is like `"31..."` and not `"13..."`